# Bypass raw string based on the type of model property in jersey respone?

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I have a model class that has a property of type 'Object'.

```
class Model{
    private Object data;
    ......
}
```

When I return the response :

```
return Response.ok(modelObject).build();
```

if 'data' is of string type, I want to bypass it as raw string to avoid quotes escaping as it is JSON format. I found that **@JsonRawValue** does the work. However, if 'data' is some object other than string, it produces the entire response in plain text format. (return type is MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

My requirement is to apply the annotation only when data is of String type else don't apply.
Is there a way to achieve this or if there is any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plain string is not a JSON, so your  response should be text/plain in this case and not application/json

Add TEXT_PLAIN to your @Produces

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public Response myService()
```

And set the mediatype according to response content

```
return Response.ok(modelObject).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

return Response.ok(plainString).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
```

Comment: It is necessary for me to return the modelObject only. I can change the Object data member to be of String type or anything else. Is there any way for this case?

Comment: Yo can not mix serializing a json string raw and an object in the same `data` object. If you need that field contains always a json raw string, change it to 'String' type and add `@JsonRawValue` as you did. When you need to send an object, serialize previously the content as string and set the value of `data`

Comment: Be aware of the warning in `http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRawValue.html`  _Warning: the resulting JSON stream may be invalid depending on your input value._